# Angular/SCSS build appending path to inline SVGs

Tags: angular, sass

I'm building a project using Angular 15 with SCSS styles. I have package pulling in SCSS files that I intend to import into this application. It has some inline SVGs in the SCSS I'm pulling where the url path starts with `data:image/svg+xml`.

When building this project, I'm getting the following error:

> `Can't resolve '../../node_modules/ui-components/src/styles/data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http:/www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='24' height='24'><path fill='black' d='M19 13H5v-2h14v2Z'/></svg>`

Looks like the build process is appending a path to the node_modules directory instead of leaving alone inline assets that start with `data:image`.

Is there a way to configure the build process to ignore appending the path here? Preferably one that doesn't involve ejecting the app.